# In pytorch, Multi-gpus don't work, How can I solve this?

Tags: pytorch, multi-gpu

I have a question about working with multi-GPUs.

I use 4 GPU 1080ti. I want to use them for deeplearning.

I ran the data parallelism example in the PyTorch tutorial, but it doesn't work. I also reinstalled CUDA (10.2, 11.0) and reinstalled the OS. (I used linux mint and reinstalled both 19 and 20.) But the result was always the same.

On `nvidia-smi` it looks like this:

[image]

The terminal running Python is in this state:
[image]

Comment: is it possible your input batch is too small to share across 4 GPUs? Have you tired using [horovod](https://horovod.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pytorch.html)?

Comment: @Shai Thank you for advice, but I tried using horovod, it didn't work also.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: In your `nvidia-smi` it seems like 3 out of 4 GPUs are fully utilized and the fourth one allocated memory - my guess is that all of them work and you just need to `nvidia-smi` more often to actually see that.